# Unable to perform Bokeh export_png from docker image

Tags: docker, bokeh

When attempting to run a Jupyter notebook that runs export_png via nbconvert in a Docker container, I get the following error.

```
 Neither firefox and geckodriver nor a variant of chromium browser and chromedriver are available on system PATH. You can install the former with 'conda install -c conda-forge firefox geckodriver'.
```

I have a Linux vm configured with similar dependencies and it all works fine.  I see there is a bug around finding firefox if the path points to a script, but mine does not, as shown in the last lines of output below.  I'm starting to think the runtime error produced is a red herring and it's actually throwing a different error, but hardcoded to that message.

Are there any know issues of running bokeh export_png within a docker image?  Any necessary config?  Anyone doing that successfully with versions of firefox, geckodriver, selenium, and bokeh you could share?  Installing chromium instead is not easy, as this is all behind a company conda mirror without those packages.

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/io/webdriver.py in get(self)
    116         if not self.reuse or self.current is None:
    117             self.reset()
--> 118             self.current = self.create()
    119         return self.current
    120

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/io/webdriver.py in create(self, kind)
    120
    121     def create(self, kind: Optional[DriverKind] = None) -> WebDriver:
--> 122         driver = self._create(kind)
    123         self._drivers.add(driver)
    124         return driver

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/bokeh/io/webdriver.py in _create(self, kind)
    138                 return driver
    139
--> 140             raise RuntimeError("Neither firefox and geckodriver nor a variant of chromium browser and " \
    141                                "chromedriver are available on system PATH. You can install the former " \
    142                                "with 'conda install -c conda-forge firefox geckodriver'.")

RuntimeError: Neither firefox and geckodriver nor a variant of chromium browser and chromedriver are available on system PATH. You can install the former with 'conda install -c conda-forge firefox geckodriver'.
RuntimeError: Neither firefox and geckodriver nor a variant of chromium browser and chromedriver are available on system PATH. You can install the former with 'conda install -c conda-forge firefox geckodriver'.

[g_de_auto@0ff0d47b4a0f data_science_foundation]$ which firefox
/opt/conda/bin/FirefoxApp/firefox
[g_de_auto@0ff0d47b4a0f data_science_foundation]$ which geckodriver
/opt/conda/bin/geckodriver
[g_de_auto@0ff0d47b4a0f data_science_foundation]$ cat /opt/conda/bin/FirefoxApp/firefox
ELF>@@1@8
         @@@@@@h@@@@@@  @ @-=@=@-=@=@0@@DDPtd` ` @` @<<QtdRtd-=@=@PP/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2GNU GNUB
m5Jzq
       ms- libpthread.so.0__errno_locationlibdl.so.2__gmon_start__libstdc++.so.6libm.so.6libgcc_s.so.1libc.so.6execv__stack_chk_fail_]`@@D]fD`@@UH`@@HHHH?HHtHt @@(@@0@@8@@@@@H@H/Ht5/%/@%/h%/h%/h%/h%/h%/h%/h%R/f1I^HHPTI@Hp@H@fDU`@@H=`@@HtHt
17dH%(H;tf.DAWAAVIAUIATL%(+UH-(+SL)1H]HtLLDAHH9u[]A\A]A^A_ff./proc/self/exeCouldn't find the application directory.
-binExec failed with error: %s
```

**Update**
The underlying error I get out of the _try_create_firefox_webdriver function is SessionNotCreatedException('Unable to find a matching set of capabilities')

Comment: I wonder if there is a flag that can be passed to docker run that enables a graphic subsystem or custom web driver options to resolve this.  Still don't have it working.  Tried --gpus all in the run command, but I get an error when attempting that.

Comment: Trying to decide between using Xvfb for a virtual frame buffer with some related configuration changes in the export, or going with Kaleido.  I have yet to find a Kaleido scope for Bokeh or any Bokeh related examples of exporting with Kaleido.

Answer (score 0):

Chose to use Xvfb.  Looked into Kaleido, but I did not see an easy integration with Bokeh.  Steps were:

Install the following dependencies.

```
yum install gtk3-devel xorg-x11-server-Xvfb.x86_64 selenium geckodriver=0.26.0 firefox=74.0
```

Telling firefox what display to use (the virtual one).

```
export DISPLAY=:0
```

Launch Xvfb along with my command.

```
Xvfb :0 -screen 0 1920x1080x24 & script_that_turns_charts_to_images
```